# Separating the header/footer from content with Angular 4

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, angular

I've started learning to use Angular and so far it seems fairly straight forward. I opted to convert one of my existing website themes over to familiarize myself with the process but ran into a question regarding proper usage.

My understanding thus far is that each page is a component. I have my index content in **app.component.html**, and then each sub page is a separate component as well. I would however like to separate the `header/footer` HTML and include it as I have in the past with PHP.

My question is, should the `header/footer` be individual components or should they just be singular HTML files, included using `ng-include`? I realize either would work but can't figure out which is the traditional implementation with Angular developers.

I am trying the following approach but the header/footer component's don't seem to load. They work fine from app.component.html but not from index.html.

index.html

```
<body>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</body>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    ProductsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create Header and footer components and use it in `AppComponent`.

This is helpful if you want to use i18n tools like `translate` or if you want to change the header or footer if user is logged in.

The app Structure should be something like this.

```
AppComponent
|
|----> HeaderComponent
|----> Router-Outlet ---> Page content should be in the container.
|----> FooterComponent
```

This is how you need to have the files. You cannot have the components in index.html as the angular bootstraps for app not for other components.

Comment: No, create them as components and include them like `<appHeader>` and `<appFooter>` do not use `ng-include`.

Comment: I updated the original post to show the code I have now but it doesn't load the header/footer, only the app-root. Any idea why? If I add <app-header></app-header> to the app.component.html it works but not when added to the index.html as shown above.

Comment: You have those components? have you imported them in appModule?

Comment: I do have those components (they work when linked from app.component.html, just not index.html) and they were automatically added to app.module.ts, the import and declarations are there.

Comment: Add the `appHeader` and `appFooter` in template of `AppComponent`. Not in index.html